# Angular 2/4: How do I make readonly work with my custom component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a custom component which has a label and a input box. I want to make the input box readonly. How do I achieve the below?

```
<custom-component [readonly]=true>
```

My custom component template is below

```
<div>
    <div><label>Hello</label></div>
    <div><input class="input input-lg" id="float-input" type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="value"
           (change)="onChange(value)" (keydown)="onChange(value)" (keyup)="onChange(value)"
           (keypress)="onChange(value)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874688/how-to-disable-an-input-type-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Input variable in your component:

```
@Input() readOnly: Boolean;
```

use from your **parent** call like you indicate upside:

```
<custom-component [readOnly]="true"></custom-component>
```

and use this input variable to define the read-only value in your form:

```
<input class="input input-lg" 
  id="float-input" type="text" size="30" 
  pInputText [readonly]="readOnly"
  (change)="onChange(value)" (keydown)="onChange(value)" 
  (keyup)="onChange(value)" (keypress)="onChange(value)"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly make your component to readonly. Just take a input in your component and use it in your component to make readonly to input

```
<custom-component [readonlyComp]="true">
```

In your component take a Input

@Input() readonlyComp: boolean;

Use readonlyComp in your component template.

```
<div>
    <div><label>Hello</label></div>
    <div><input class="input input-lg" id="float-input" type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="value" [readonly]="readonlyComp"
           (change)="onChange(value)" (keydown)="onChange(value)" (keyup)="onChange(value)"
           (keypress)="onChange(value)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help