# How to make option element readonly but not disabled the select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried setting readonly attribute to true, but it did not work as i am still able to select the value from dropdown.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="type" tabindex="0">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="first">first</option> 
            <option value="second">second</option>
        </select> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Actual code:

<tr>
 <td><select name="type" tabindex="0">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first">first</option>
  <option value="second">second</option></select>
 </td>
</tr>

Comment: where did you put readonly in your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable an input type=text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874688/how-to-disable-an-input-type-text)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `disabled` on `options` instead of the whole `select` tag

```html
<select name="type" tabindex="0">
 <option value="" disabled></option>
 <option value="first" disabled>first</option> 
<option value="second" disabled>second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok this way , Will I able to submit the value in the form ?

Comment: Yes you can submit the value in the form for the options which are "not disabled". The disabled ones will not be selected hence cannot be submitted.

Comment: No, basically I dont want user to select the value from dropdown but I need to myself set the value of dropdown according to some other fields below dropdown. So even I can hide also th options but whatevr value i set ..it should submit in form.

Comment: Ya you can give a default value to the select on the time of submission via js

Comment: Is it possible, If i stop user from expanding the dropdown itself?

Comment: Yes, set the disabled on the select tag

Comment: hmm that will not allow me to submit the type in form then, anyways I will go ahead with disabling options.

Comment: If you want you can custom dropdown that will give you more control including styling.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#select').change( function() {
    if($(this).val() !== '')  console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="type" tabindex="0" id="select"> 
     <option value=""></option> 
     <option value="first" disabled>first</option> 
     <option value="second" disabled>second</option>
      <option value="Not disabled">Not disabled</option>
</select>
```